# pandas-read-xml has error on 'json-normalize'

Tags: pandas, readxml

I saw there is a way to directly read XML files using pandas. I followed and used this package. However, I keep getting errors.

https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

The error was generated by last line and the error is

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'json_normalize'
```

I am using kernel python 3, can anyone tell me what was wrong with it?

Comment: What happens with "from pandas import json_normalize"?

Comment: This also shows the same error